# How to customize error message css in pardot forms

Tags: css, forms, customization, pardot

How to add CSS to Pardot form fields when error messages occurred without breaking form layout.

I tried to add css to pardot form error fields to set them 50% and the whole layout changed.

Comment: Could you please add your code directly to the question